# scanf C program

Tags: c, scanf

So I have been looking at a C program code and there was a code snippet that has me really confused. I am new to C, and I haven't seen any coding styling in C like this.

```
i = 0;
while (1 == scanf("/%[^/ \t\n]", a[i++]))
  printf(">%s<\n", a[i-1]);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @freestyle My question is what does that code i provided do?

Comment: "As long as the function scanf returns 1 (while assigning to a[i] and postincrementing), output a[i]." (The -1 to take the postincrement into account.) Now, read about the functions scanf and printf.

Comment: @YvesDaoust whats all the stuff in the scanf?

Comment: Hem, read about scanf.

Comment: It scans strings which start by character `/` and have not characters `/ \t\n`. Then prints them. It's look like crazy a file path parsing.

Comment: @freestyle thank you. I'll look more into it.

Comment: @freestyle: "It scans strings which start by character `/` and have not characters `/ \t\n`" - that is not entirely accurate. It requires its input to begin with `/`, but *ignores* (skips) that `/`. After that it reads into `a[i]` everything till the next whitespace or `/`.

Comment: @AnT Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking at is simple a [format string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string).

In this case:

`while (1 == scanf("/%[^/ \t\n]", a[i++])) { ... }`

1. The scanf statement should return exactly one value.
   The loop terminates when it gets anything besides "1" (e.g. "0", at end of file).
2. The value will be written to `a[]`.
3. The index (`a[i++]`) is incremented each pass through the loop
4. And, from Beej's Guide:

> https://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/scanf.html
>
> **%[**
>
> This is about the weirdest format specifier there is. It allows you to specify a set of characters to be stored away (likely in an
>   array of chars). Conversion stops when a character that is not in the
>   set is matched.
>
> For example, %[0-9] means "match all numbers zero through nine." And %[AD-G34] means "match A, D through G, 3, or 4".
>
> Now, to convolute matters, you can tell scanf() to match characters that are not in the set by putting a caret (^) directly
>   after the %[ and following it with the set, like this: %[^A-C], which
>   means "match all characters that are not A through C."
>
> To match a close square bracket, make it the first character in the set, like this: %[]A-C] or %[^]A-C]. (I added the "A-C" just so it
>   was clear that the "]" was first in the set.)
>
> To match a hyphen, make it the last character in the set: %[A-C-].
>
> So if we wanted to match all letters except "%", "^", "]", "B", "C", "D", "E", and "-", we could use this format string: %[^]%^B-E-].

Comment: Now thats a great way to answer @YvesDaous. Thank you!

Comment: Yet this answer does not even mention the leading `/` in the `scanf` format. Why was it left unexplained?

Comment: @AnT: As Freestyle explained above: 
   
"It scans strings which start by character `/` and have not characters `/ \t\n`".  As you elaborated: "It ignores (skips) that /. After that it reads into a[i] everything till the next whitespace or /".